# Can add author filed when import test case via api interface?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I import a test case into Kiwi TCMS via API interface, find Author filed is “Admin”. I want to add author filed. I add an “author” key and with a value in values dict. But author is still displayed as Admin.

I use the following API:

```
 rpc_client = tcms_api.TCMS()._server
 rpc_client.Auth.login('admin', 'admin')
 self.rpc_client.TestCase.create(values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friendly warning:

> self.rpc_client.TestCase.create(values)

this is a bit old, you are using an older version of Kiwi TCMS.

The new syntax (compatible with latest versions, see changelog) is:

`rpc_client = tcms_api.TCMS()
rpc_client.exec.TestCase.create(values)`

without the need to Auth.login() first. The API client will do this for you.

To answer the question. Inside of `tcms/xmlrpc/api/testcase.py::create()` we have:

> test_case = TestCase.create(author=request.user, values=form.cleaned_data)

The author is always the user that sends the API request, which is the same behavior when creating Test Case via the webUI.

If you want a different user, either configure your API client with another username.

You may also try the `TestCase.update()` API method but ATM this doesn't allow you to update the author. Please open an issue on GitHub if you want this functionality to be present (sounds like a valid use-case).

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I have updated my tcms-api package and used new API sytax. Now I understan that, the author filed read from ~/.tcms.conf file we configured. If we wanto change author, need change the ~/.tcms.conf file. So, seems update author make sense. I will open a GitHub issue latter.